# Как открыть изображение с помощью c#?

Tags: c#

Я просмотрел много статей и видео о том как открыть какой-то файл, но везде говориться про `FileStream` который мне вообще не нужен. Мне нужно просто открыть картинку как-будто я просто два раза нажал на неё.

Метод `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(FilePath);` не работает, выдает ошибку -
`System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform."`

Comment: скорее нужно какой-то вьювер для картинок вызвать через процесс.старт и передать путь к файлу

Comment: старо как мир `Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = FilePath, UseShellExecute = true });` https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute

Comment: Спасибо большое!